# Centering Content Within a Table Column With CSS in IE6/7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a table where the content of one column is often narrower than the column itself. I would like the content of this column to be centred like so:

```
-----------------
| Column Header |
-----------------
|    Content    |
|    Content    |
|    Content    |
-----------------
```

A quick search turned up the solution of placing the content in a `div` with `style="diplay:table; margin:auto"`, however this does not work in IE6/7 as they do not recognise `table` as a display mode. I would prefer to avoid explicitly setting `width` as the size of the content may vary.

Is there a hack to make this display the same way in IE6/7? Alternatively, is there a different approach which works across IE6/7 and all the major browsers?

**EDIT:** I cannot use `text-align:center;` as the content is not plain text.

**EDIT 2:** Here is simple example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KK5Bp/. The button appears centred under the heading in sane browsers, but is still left aligned in IE6/7. I would like it to appear the same way in IE6/7 as well.

Comment: Why don't you place your problem on http://jsfiddle.net so we can view it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `text-align: center` on `<div>` inside the relevant table cells?

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Very Long Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    <button name="short">short</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`text-align:center` should work the same in every browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NYYwd/

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in the question that the content is not just text. I will update accordingly.

Comment: @veredesmarald: I added a tiny update, I think moving `text-align: center` to the `<div>` and dropping the `display` from the `<div>` should do the trick.

Comment: Yep that seems to do the trick, thanks. Funny, I thought I tried that before... Oh well.

Comment: @veredesmarald: Trying to make IE6 and IE7 behave themselves does bad things to your brain, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try margin: 0px auto?
Give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: This does not work in IE6/7 as they ignore the diplay:table and display the `div` as a block element with width=100% (and therefore margin 0). I don't want to explicitly set the width of the `div` as the content is dynamic (but often short).